# PostgreSQL UPDATE query with Node.js throws error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to do a `PostGRESQL` `update` with `Node.js`, and I get the following `error : source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression`

I have been using the same `principle` for `create, read, delete,` and I had no issues.

What can be wrong ?

**Here is my code** :

```
var pg = require("pg")
var pgClient = new pg.Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'tutorial',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
})

pgClient.connect(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Could not connect to postgres:', err)
        process.exit()
    }
    console.log("Connected to postgres");
});

var aParams = ["Jenny", 1]
var sQuery = 'UPDATE public.users SET (name) = ($1) WHERE (id) = ($2)';
pgClient.query(sQuery, aParams, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        process.exit()
    }
    console.log(res.rows)
})
```

Comment: Does it help if you remove the unnecessary parentheses?

Comment: thank you so much for noticing. it works now. it´s so weird cause I used column names with paranthesis in other queries, however I had only one column named in that cases. probably that´s the reason. but still isn´t a logical one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for setting a column value is

```
name = $1
```

and not

```
(name) = ($1)
```